# How to reduce html or body width with media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I simply want to reduce desktop view width slightly but can't get it to work with media query. My latest attempt is

```
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {

   html, body {
        max-width: 80%;
   }
}
```

but it has no affect. I don't think I want to mess with container b/c that would leave out the navbar. Using my own stylesheet (added below bootstrap cdn stuff) rather than using the media queries directly in template.html but I don't know if that makes any difference. Am I trying to do this the right way or am I completely missing something?

Comment: That should definitely be doing something on viewports between 992–1199.98px wide. Are you overriding the max-width somewhere else?

Comment: Media query is valid, it might be that some other styles are preventing your settings. You could always try `max-width: 80% !important;`

Comment: That DOES have an effect. Are you sure your window size is within those boundaries?

Comment: I presume that you have added the viewport tag for that(`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want go banging around on high-level elements when using a layout library. This limits what you and others can do in the page later (say you want a full-width banner somewhere). You also probably don't want to casually override *all* instances of a Bootstrap class.

In this case, look at adding a custom class to the `.container` or `.container-fluid` element, limiting its width:

```
.container.narrow {
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Use that for any containers where you want a narrower width, and use containers *without* that class for wider content.

```
<div class="container narrow"> ... </div>
```

Whether you apply this in a media query is probably immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

I was strugglng to find the answer to my screen not working correctly for the mobile and below answer from you worked like a charm. Thanks so much for your answer. I removed the meta-name line and it worked like a charm.

Mohan

@Beanic
I presume that you have added the viewport tag for that() –

Jan 22, 2020 at 12:50

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32844092)